# unable to block out-going traffic

Tags: centos, iptables

I've run

> > $ iptables -I OUTPUT -j DROP -d [ip address]

and found that some processes are still connecting the destination ip I've blocked above:

> > $ lsof -p [pid]

it shows:

> > perl         3u  IPv4 235988255               TCP hostname:54160->:ircd (SYN_SENT)

Please can I have some advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Because all you're doing is preventing applications from responding to the initial request. The application can see someone trying to connect from that IP address, it sends the SYN-ACK in response but the SYN-ACK never makes it to the network because of your firewall rule.

The end result is that each side of the conversation is waiting for the other side to say something else. That's why it's stuck in a half-open state (SYN_SENT).

If you're only going to add a single rule you need to do it on the INPUT chain so that `ircd` never sees someone make the connection attempt.